# Wordpress how to link a page to blog content

Tags: wordpress, button, hyperlink, blogs

This may seem novice, but I assure its not.
So, I have a site, which displays blog posts by date from new backwards.
Standard stuff.  However, what I'm trying to do is create a temporary homepage, lets call it 'yogo'.  It displays some ad, or image, with a button link.

What I'd like is a direct link to the actual blog feed which displays in a given theme site's frontpage.  Is it just a block?
When Im in Appearance->Reading, I can change homepage to 'yogo' fine.  But, say a visitor is on 'yogo', and I want a button they click on to link to what would be the original theme frontpage with blog content, it should technically be 'Home' but is that coded somewhere through the wordpress software like the Reading mentioned above.
Maybe Im missing something, should I shut off permalinks, and dig for it in actual page extension?
Im trying to avoid using Guten. or Elem. to build out a blog page.

Any advice, thanks in advance.

Comment: Need to more clarify for good Understand. @16998112

Comment: We call that templates - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/ . For default templates read this - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/custom-front-page-templates/ If you create front-page.php and home.php you can easly set your banner url etc. Or use function in your index.php or page.php template w/e you use and use conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Once add your code in front-page.php or home.php you can use get_the_permalink() function to get the blog page URL and will pass in "a" HTML tag like this -

```
<a href="<?PHP echo get_the_permalink(YOUR_BLOG_POST_ID); ?>" target="_blank">Your Blog Name</a>
```

Might be it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Just  a quick update. actually solved this.. In simple terms, it is possible to do this really quickly through the Wpress UI.  From  your backend, these are the steps in the following order: 
(firstly.  shout out 2 user 'mirchev' because if u didn't point out templates I would of been way off.  actually after about an hour of research after that) 
So it all takes place in Setting->Reading.  From what I've read, Wpress started off as a blog based system anyways, so it was solved a long time back.  
Basically to start, 
1. Create 2 pages, no need to add any content as long as they are 'new' and you make note of the names.

2.  Also important -in the template area to the right panel when the new page editor loads up (you don't need to add any texts, images or whatever, including the area on the right just make sure "default template" is selected. 
3. Afterwards, these 2 pages are 2 be used in the Setting->reading section.
What you want to do is when you enter this setting of your Wpress site, instead of having your "homepage" radio button be "latest posts" set it to 'static page,' and 
4. important - select 1 of the 2 new pages you created as the static page.  
5. Now, also important, for the posts page, select the 2nd of the 2 new pages you created.  
6. Once this is done, what happens is your website loads the static page, which you may customize however, and then you can go into your Appearance->menus and add the appropriate link to the 2nd of the 2 new pages you created to load the blog, or link to it whichever way you choose. More often than not a menu item should appear if that is the setting you customized.

..And that is all.  if fact I was very surprised just how smooth it was.
good luck !  ..--'''~~**

[Separation!](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-separate-page-for-blog-posts-in-wordpress/#:~:text=%20How%20to%20Create%20a%20Separate%20Page%20for,Your%20Website%E2%80%99s%20Navigation%20Menu.%20Now%20that...%20More%20)